# How to lock ImageView orientation in Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, screen-rotation

How to lock ImageView orientation when rotate screen in Kotlin? simply how to freeze ImageView (as background) when rotate activity?

Trying:
I tried to change a image in LinearLayout as background,
and use this method but it is not working!!

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig : Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearBg)
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_landscape)
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_portrait)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to lock the entire screen?  Then you'd set the orientation for the activity in your manifest.  If you're looking to lock just the one view that's not possible.

Comment: Why it's not possible? What about change ImageView 90 degree when rotate screen or become landscape?

Comment: Because rotation causes the original Activity to be destroyed and a new one created.  It then starts that activity.  So the old screen is completely deleted and gone.  You can override that behavior, but even if you do, it will cause a new layout/measure cycle with the new orientation's width/height.  So everything gets resized and relocated on screen.  You can lock the orientation for the entire screen, but the idea of locking a view isn't a concept that exists or makes sense.  If you just want to rotate the image that can be done, but that isn't locking its orientation.

Comment: To rotate it you can just apply a rotation matrix to the image view.  But you'd need to figure out what direction to rotate it in.  You'd either need to decide one orientation is correct and rotate it relative to that, or you'd need to track the change in orientation, probably by overriding the orientation change behavior and rotating it in onConfigurationChanged..

Comment: TO make that work you'd need to add android:configChanges="orientation" to your activity in the manifest.  But if this is all you want to do, it can be done more easily:  create a landscape override folder for landscape (create a folder called drawable-land) and put the image you're calling bg_landscape in there and just call it bg.  Keep the portrait one in the drawable folder and just call it bg.  Then just set the background to bg in your xml, when it reloads the activity it will automatically pick the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val screenOrientation = this.resources.configuration.orientation
    if (screenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // TODO
    } else {
        // TODO
    }
```